# iOS not supported by Xcode : Could not locate device support files

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, beta

iOS (beta) device support files are usually distributed with Xcode (beta) and can be found under `/Applications/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` however, **latest iOS device support files can't be located within latest Xcode beta** Package Contents.

Is anyone aware of a download location, where these files could be available for [**latest** iOS beta Releases](https://developer.apple.com/news/releases/)?

> Xcode: Could Not Locate Device Support Files

Comment: What version of iOS beta do you have and what version of Xcode are you running?

Comment: Check this GitHub repo for support files. https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport

Comment: Xcode 11 beta 3 (11M362V) that has iOS beta 13.0 bundled, I am looking for iOS 13 beta 3 (17A5522g) DSF

Comment: download the latest xcode beta

Comment: Already mentioned, that’s not a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the **latest [iOS device support files](https://github.com/Yatko/iOS-device-support-files)** and news and updates here: [Releases - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/news/releases/).